# Make DIV fullscreen regardless of position

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make a DIV fullscreen regardless where it is positioned in the HTML page?
In some pages I want a DIV to overlay everything behind it, but if the body is only half the screen, my DIV also becomes half the screen instead of fullscreen.

I use this CSS:

```
.MainOverlayDIV{
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:90;
position:fixed;
top:0%;
left:0%;
background-color:#F1F2F3;
opacity:0.9;
display:none;

}
```

Comment: I later "unhide" it with Jquery when I need it, thats why display is set to none.

Comment: How can body be half the screen (by which I assume you mean 'viewport')?

Comment: When you unhide it with jquery, then set the div's width and height to be the same as `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`.

Comment: Well I think that is happening, sorry for being a noob :) My "overlay" div is member of a "maindiv", this "maindiv" is half the page. The overlaydiv needs to be inside the maindiv, but the overlaydiv should be screenfilling. Edit: I need the DIV to be screenfilling regardless of other content or where it is in the HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.MainOverlayDIV{    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100500;
}
```